# tab is displayed as "^^I" in tcblisting environment

Tags: tcolorbox

My tabs inside the `tcblisting` environment are not showing correctly and becomes "^^I". I have tried everything to fix this but not worked. Could anyone please help me so the tabs are displayed correctly in `tcblisting`? (As illustrated in the sample code, `lstlisting` seems have no problem with tabs.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},stringstyle=\color{Maroon},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, frame=tb, rulesepcolor=\color{Gray},
showspaces=false, showstringspaces=false,
tabsize=4, aboveskip=10pt, belowskip=10pt,
lineskip=2pt, breaklines,
autogobble}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First     % some comment
    \item Second
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcblisting}
\begin{lstlisting}{}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First     % some comment
        \item Second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome Richard! Just a note for anyone testing the MWE: the StackExchange interface converts tabs into spaces, so you'll have to put the tabs back in manually.

Comment: I can only reproduce the issue if I compile with XeLaTeX. Is this the engine you're using?

Comment: Since a tab is in fact `^^I`, i would say this is correct. How do you want to distingush between a tab and space?

Comment: To egreg, yes, i'm using XeLaTeX for compilation. Is it possible to show tabs correctly in XeLaTeX? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Johannes_B, can a tab be shown as, say 4 spaces, instead of "^^I" in the final result? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Paul, could you please tell me how to manually insert a <tab> character in code blocks of my post? I've been doing research on this for half an hour and couldn't find a solution. I give up :(

Comment: @richard1017 you can't; that's why I left the note about it. :-)

Comment: @richard1017 The problem is exactly like the one described in the question this one I marked as duplicate of. The issue is indeed that `tcolorbox` writes the environment's content to a file; with XeTeX you need the `-8bit` command line option in order to write tabs literally.

Comment: Hi egreg, thank you very much. I'm writing my latex in Sublime Text and my builder settings are:
"command": ["texify", "-b", "-p", "--engine=xetex", "--tex-option=\"--synctex=1\""]
It seems "-8bit" option doesn't work for texify.
Anyway, I changed the engine to pdflatex and tabs are shown correctly.